# Убрать белые границы у фотографий и картинок

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Помогите пожалуйста! При загрузки страницы explorer 10 отображает белые границы у фотографий и картинок jpg, phg, gif. Как можно убрать эти белые границы?

Comment: Кусочек верстки в студию !:)

Comment: Например вот этот: 

    <div id="avt">
    <a href=""><img src="img/avto.jpg" /></a>
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#avt img {border: none;}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Все получилось!

Answer (score 1):

В простейшем случае, вам нужно прописать:

```
#avt img {
border: none;
}
```

Если не поможет, то возможно вы наблюдаете не бордер, а чей-то background-color из за наличия паддингов и маржинов. Последовательно пропишете для ссылки и дива какой нибудь яркий background, это поможет вам быстрее понять что происходит. Если проблема подтвердится , выставляее padding и margin в нули.

P.S. Добрый совет: потратьте 1-3 часа чтобы вникнуть в инструмент под названием firebug если  у вас firefox, и Developer tools если у вас Chrome.